# How to find a proper div related to another one when focusing on a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, onfocus

I am trying to do the following :

```
<div class="messageNewComment">
<form style="margin:0px;" action="cible.php" method="post">

<textarea class="content"></textarea>
<div class="button_block">
<input type="submit" class="button" value=" Partager "/>
<input type="submit" class="cancel" value=" Annuler " />
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

The textarea grows when you focus on it and the button_block shows up using jquery. It works fine when I have only one section like this above but as I am going to have multiples comment area i would like the proper button_block to show up ... How can I achieve that ?

here is my jquery code :

```
$(function() 
{
$(".content").focus(function()
{
$(this).height("50px"); //animate({"height": "50px",}, "fast" );
if ($(this).height() == 50) {
$(".button_block").slideDown("fast");
}
return false;
});

$(".cancel").click(function()
{
/*if ($(".content").height() != 50) {*/
$(".content").height("20px"); //animate({"height": "20px",}, "fast" );
$(".button_block").slideUp("fast");
return false;
//}
});
```

As of now, every button_block of the page show up ... so that it is not very convenient ;)

Any idea ?

Thks a lot !

Gotye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$(".button_block").slideDown("fast");
```

With

```
$(this).next(".button_block").slideDown("fast");
```

Your selector will select all elements with class `button_block`, but what we need the button block that follows the text area with focus. So we can use the [jquery next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selector.

The same logic should be used to slideup the buttons as well.

```
$(this).parent(".button_block").slideUp("fast").prev(".content").height("20px");
```

Here we can use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) and [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selectors

Answer (score 1):

Because the div is a sibling .next should do the trick:

```
$(".content").focus(function()
{
$(this).height("50px"); //animate({"height": "50px",}, "fast" );
if ($(this).height() == 50) {
$(this).next(".button_block").slideDown("fast");
}
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

traverse the tree with `next()`

```
$(".content").focus(function(){
    $(this).height(50).val('').next(".button_block").show();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

keegan3d's answer is right as long as ur div is just after the textarea.
if any other element happens to come in between them in the future , u could use this:

```
$(function() 
{
$(".content").focus(function()
{
$(this).height("50px"); //animate({"height": "50px",}, "fast" );
if ($(this).height() == 50) {
$(this).nextAll(".button_block:first").slideDown("fast");
return false;
});
```